# File Download on button click depending on URL name

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to experiment in a File Sharing Web App on localhost I am trying to work on, and well...I am having a slight problem, maybe I am not being too good at explaining it so I am not getting the answer I need but I will try my best to explain here.

So I am trying to make a 'Download Page' For the files uploaded, and I would like to have the button-onclick download a different file depending on the URL, and I want to show the file size on the button while I am doing so. (Similar to how Mediafire download pages to files work if that helps in any way)

I am not sure if I explained it well enough but the main issue is I want the file downloaded on button click to depend on the URL name. Is that possible to do? If not, is there any alternatives? Anywhere help would be appreciated here, thank you for your time!

Comment: Which bit are you stuck with?  Working out how to get a file size?  Putting a button on the web page?  Changing the URL?

Comment: @Neil I am pretty sure I can work my way around the file size, and putting the button on the webpage is easy enough...The URL is the main problem here though

Comment: Think of it the other way around, don't change the button action depending on the URL, just create the button with the correct URL you want.

Comment: it is possible, what have you tried so far and how are you storing the files?

Comment: @Neil Any hints I can use there? Like is there something specific I can use or research about the whole URL thing? I am still pretty new to it and I don't even know how to change or make a button react to a URL I want. Thanks for your reply by the way

Comment: @TiisetsoTjabane Currently I am using a FileUploadControl and storing files on a specific folder on the server file. And regarding the URL part, I am not sure if I am bad at searching online but I really have been having no luck in finding anything...So I don't even know the basics of URL editting

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, note my current solution is in dotnet core controller.

```
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<FileResult> ExportExtraAsync(int id)
    {
        // get file details in db
        var toDownload = await unitOfWork.ExtrasRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);
       // build a file path
        IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.GetDirectoryName(toDownload.FileDirectory));
        IFileInfo fileInfo = provider.GetFileInfo(Path.GetFileName(toDownload.FileDirectory));
        var readStream = fileInfo.CreateReadStream();
        // return a file stream, this will force the browser to download
        return File(readStream, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, Path.GetFileName(toDownload.FileDirectory));
    }
```

The url would be `"/api/Extras/ExportExtraAsync?id=123"` where id can change and allowing for downloading different files for different urls.